# Multiple Audio starting on

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to start an audio whenever a user clicks on the page (since autoplay doesn't work anymore on most browsers), and I've managed to do so by using an eventlistener on ngOnInit which works fine on the first click. My problem is that when I click multiple times the audio starts playing multiple times, so I'd need to remove the listener from it. I've tried a basic solution like using the `once: true` flag or removing the listener after the audio played, but with no success. This is the code snippet I'm using:

```
  ngOnInit() {
  document.querySelector('ion-content').addEventListener('click', this.playAudio);
  
  }

  playAudio(){
   console.log('started');
   let audio = new Audio();
   audio.src="http://192.168.1.15:8000/example1.ogg";
   audio.load();
   audio.play();
   document.querySelector('ion-content').removeEventListener('click', this.playAudio);
   console.log("removed")

}
```

Why wouldn't this work?

Comment: set global variable IsClicked as false. Then wrap code in playAudio() with if(!isClicked){...} . and inside 'if' also set variable IsClicked to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is a debounce method to not delay your functions calls when called multiple times :

```
private clickTimeout = null;

//better way of doing is attach a click event handler on the ion-content in the HTML 

ngOnInit() {
  document.querySelector('ion-content').addEventListener('click', this.getItem());
  
  }

public getItem(): void {

  if (this.clickTimeout) {

      this.setClickTimeout(() => {});

  } else {

    // if timeout doesn't exist, we know it's first click 
    // treat as single click until further notice

    this.setClickTimeout((itemId) =>  
       this.handleSingleClick());
  }
}


// sets the click timeout and takes a callback 
// for what operations you want to complete when
// the click timeout completes

public setClickTimeout(callback) {
  // clear any existing timeout

  clearTimeout(this.clickTimeout);

  this.clickTimeout = setTimeout(() => {

    this.clickTimeout = null;
    callback();

  }, 200);

}
public handleSingleClick(itemId: string) {
   //The actual action that should be performed on click      
   this.playAudio()
}
```

You should check [this](https://medium.com/ngconf/how-to-handle-double-click-events-in-angular-rxjs-e318697c9e26) link to get better understanding of how this code works.